# estoy haciendo una shell, y me sale este confilto entre status, como solucionar este error de estatus en shell 127

Tags: c

**estoy haciendo una shell, y me sale este confilto entre status, como solucionar este error de estatus en shell 127**

```
[GOT]:
(stdout)[](Length: 0)
(stderr)[./hsh: 1: ls: not found
](Length: 24)
(status)[0]

[EXPECTED]:
(stdout)[](Length: 0)
(stderr)[./hsh: 1: ls: not found
](Length: 24)
(status)[127]
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!